# Is there a way to make slurm print job summary after completion?

Tags: hpc, slurm

I would like to have SLURM print job information to `stdout` or `stderr` upon completion/termination of a job.

What I would like is something like this (this was from the previous cluster I used to work on, running LSF):

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Sender: LSF System <xxx@xxx>
Subject: Job 2273357[201]: <TG.wg.window[1-779]%100> in cluster <farm> Exited

Job <TG.wg.window[1-779]%100> was submitted from host <farm-headnode> by user <username> in cluster <farm>.
Job was executed on host(s) <2*host_01>, in queue <normal>, as user <username> in cluster <farm>.
</home/username> was used as the home directory.
</my/working/directory> was used as the working directory.
Started at Sat Jan 28 01:00:22 2017
Results reported on Sat Jan 28 01:02:28 2017

Your job looked like:

------------------------------------------------------------
# LSBATCH: User input
./tmp.616856.exe $LSB_JOBINDEX
------------------------------------------------------------

Exited with exit code 1.

Resource usage summary:

    CPU time :                                   112.44 sec.
    Max Memory :                                 25 MB
    Average Memory :                             20.38 MB
    Total Requested Memory :                     1000.00 MB
    Delta Memory :                               975.00 MB
    Max Swap :                                   264 MB
    Max Processes :                              15
    Max Threads :                                15
```

Currently, my SLURM cluster has the following behaviour:

- when I run a job through srun, I get the exit code or a success message, or an error message if the job was terminated by Slurm itself for resource reasons
- when I run a job through `sbatch -e errfile -o outfile --wrap="command"`, both the error and output file are empty if `command` doesn't itself write to stdout/err. In particular if `command` exits with an exit code, there is no trace in the files.

I know I can do `scontrol show job [jobid]` but this only keeps job info for a couple hours. I have seen suggestions to write a wrapper script that would essentially run that command after the job exits, but ideally I don't want to write a complicated wrapper script or schedule more jobs. I am looking for a configuration option that would dump job info to stderr/out or to a file.

TIA

Disclaimer: I am a user of this cluster, not an admin. Just trying to figure out if this is possible and relay the required configuration changes to my sysadmin.

Comment: Is `scontrol` is out of scope because the job is old, check `sacct`. You can find the exit status there.

Comment: Thanks, how long do the records in `sacct` persist for by default?

Comment: Forever. Or until the SysAdmin decides to remove the DDBB, nuke the CPD and flee XD

Comment:  Okay, so is this is the way that people usually check for job info after completion? instead of having it dumped to file or email I mean

Comment: Yes. SLURM keeps a DB with all jobs' information, so this is the standard way of querying for any job data. Having this data dumped into an output file makes it hard to find this data (it is not centralized) and to work with it. Having it centralized in a DB makes it easy to find and easy to work with.

Comment: @Poshi can you create an answer with `sacct`? I'll mark it as solution.

Comment: Sorry, but this site is for helping you solving your coding issues, not for doing the coding for you. Anyways, is you only need to see the exist status of a job after it dissapears from `scontrol`, a simple `sacct -j "$jobid"` will be enough.

Comment: Of course, I had figured out how to use `sacct` in the meantime. I just wanted to make it clearer for future SO users by having an actual answer rather than a comment. It would also have added you some rep for answering.

Comment: So nice :-)
If you have the solution to the question, you can post your own code and mark it as the accepted answer, for the future SO users.